# Cannot resolve configuration property in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this property in the property file:

```
openai.api.key = sk-ApWyvjABoX5WHMOX48RUT3BlbkFJvZRs1HGKXNHqsNHQyPq2s
```

and in my class:

```
@Value("openai.api.key")
String apiKey;
```

but i have this message:

```
Cannot resolve configuration property 'openai.api.key'
```

and does not replace its value

Comment: Try without spaces before and after the equals sign

Comment: same result as before

Comment: try with `@Value("${openai.api.key}")`

Answer (score 1):

**You should get the value like this** and don't forget to add getters & setters for that particular field.

```
@Value("${openai.api.key}")
private String apiKey;
```